# After the deprecation of Web hosting on Google Drive, is there anyway to use Google Drive as a Image Repository for PHP?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I know about the recent deprecation of the Hosting on Google Drive but is there any other way to view or download the image?

I am using **service account** and I manage to upload the image but there is no way to download it or view image it unless I have permission. I am assuming since I have authenticated by the service account, I should be able to view my images without login into a google account that have permission.

I tried getting the webViewlink but still need file access.

I saw the Google Drive V3 API mention about "get" method can retrieved the content but unable to search for any documentation on that. ("Gets a file's metadata or content by ID.")

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for those who take the time to read the question.

Although the web hosting is remove from Google Drive but the Image can still be shared to Public.

1. Share to Public (Public on the web - Anyone on the Internet can find and view)
2. Use the direct link (https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILEID) to  put  into image or link.

FYI to download file you can use the webContentLink or view it on Google drive platform you can use webViewLink. 
E.g

```
$file = $service->files->get('FILEID',array('fields'=>'webViewLink'));
echo $file->webViewLink;
```

Have a nice day =)